solana_net_utils::ip_echo_server Error
When I setup rpc node, error as follows:

and solana.log has not updated other logs.
The node started and downloaded the snapshot, and the startup process lasted about 6 hours, after which this error was reported.I ran it on an r6a.8xlarge instance on AWS.
